# Comprehensive document on the history of the university system

Tags: university, academic-history

As an aspiring academic, I have been thinking a lot about why I want to be a university faculty, what my job is as a graduate student, and what role the academic community serves in the society-at-large. I realized that I severely lacked the historical background to address any of my questions. Thus:

**My Question.** Is there a comprehensive book (article, documentary, etc.) about the origins and history of the Western university system?

I would prefer a well-written book geared towards a general audience over an academic text going into the technical details of the whole story. To give a better sense of what I am looking for, I want my book to provide (either a complete or partial) answer to some of the following questions:

- What were the founding principles of the first universities?
- What is the history of the relationship between university and religion? University and State?
- Why were so many universities founded in the mid-19th century?

Comment: An interesting question, but for purposes of building or choosing a career, much of the history is irrelevant. The fact that Harvard was founded as a seminary is pretty much irrelevant to today's faculty. Likewise the fact that many state universities were originally agriculture schools.

Comment: I don’t see a strong connection between the big picture questions you put forth in the first section and the more specific ones you listed below. I recommend focusing on one or the other set.

Comment: A couple that may be of interest:   [Universities and Colleges: A Very Short Introduction](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/universities-and-colleges-a-very-short-introduction-9780198766131), [Wisdom's Workshop: The Rise of the Modern University](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691149592/wisdoms-workshop). Haven't read them myself so can't comment on the quality.

Comment: Yes, your critical qualifier _Western_ ... makes this question plausibly answerable. :) ... though I myself cannot answer it. :)